# Where is the location of the private keys of my wallet on my PC?

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows

I have searched this forum and the internet for information on the location of the private keys of my wallet on my PC and found no answers.

I am using Microsoft Windows 7 and installed the Bitcoin software from http://bitcoin.org/en/download (At the moment it is version 0.8.2)

The default installation path is C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin

In the default installation Bitcoin folder/directory, I can only see the following:

```
blocks sub-directory
chainstate sub-directory
.lock
db.log
debug.log
peers.dat
wallet.dat
```

Where are the private keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're in the wallet.dat file.